# BioPython - Retrieve sequence records from pubmed database

Tags: python, homework

I've been assigned a task to fetch sequence records from "**pubmed**" database:

> fetch 30 record of type "fasta" from (pubmed database, with term hemoglobin AND alpha) as a sequence records

It doesn't make any sense to me!

I know the PubMed database is for publications and citations, but how can I retrieve those records from it? is that even possible?

I tried to search for the IDs with a given term in it and then retrieve the records from another database (like "**nuccore**"), but I don't know if this is right.

Any ideas?

Comment: The PubMed database will not recover any sequence data - that's a database of publications. I think the question was Genbank

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @devon-ryan, converted from comment:

They meant the nucleotide database.